# $R$ matrix for XYZ spin chain

Tags: integrable-systems, spin-chains

Trying to understand how the Algebraic Bethe Ansatz works, I'm actually reading some papers and trying to apply for XXZ or XYZ model. But my problem is that I don't know how to find the R-matrix describing the considered model without using vertex models (their classical equivalent). I know that it is somehow related to quantum groups, but this is a little bit confusing, can someone tell me if starting from the Hamiltonian of XYZ/XXZ spin chain I can get the corresponding R-matrix?

Comment: The vertex models are just the Euclidean partition function with lots of complete basis insertions everywhere. What's wrong with using them?

Comment: No, i mean the point is that to derive the R-matrix of some quantum spin chain, there is a way which is to study it's classical equivalent a vertex model (XXZ spin chain  is equivalent to the 6-vertex model) my question concerns the R-matrix itself, if i can derive it expression just from the Hamiltonian of the spin chain

Comment: See my answer to a similar question of yours: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/397890