# R-matrix for spin chains

Tags: integrable-systems, spin-models, spin-chains

In algebraic Bethe ansatz procedure, one of the central objects is the R-matrix satisfying the Yang-Baxter equation, but all the papers/books give directly its expression without deriving it, so my question is How can i derive the R-matrix for XYZ/XXZ Heisenberg model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is essentially an answer to your questions [R-matrix for spin chains](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397427), [Elliptic R-matrix and Yang Baxter solution for XYZ model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397198), [$R$ matrix for XYZ spin chain](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396835), [Algebraic Bethe Ansatz and $R$-matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/396504), which all basically ask the same question anyway.

---

In short: to the best of my knowlegde, coming up with an *R*-matrix is an *art*, not a *derivation*. (Cf. the notion of a Lax pair in classical integrability.)

The quantum inverse-scattering method (QISM) was developed as a *synthesis* of the classical ISM, spin chains and lattice models. The best way to understand it is from this multi-topic point of view, rather than focussing just on spin chains. Faddeev's *How Algebraic Bethe Ansatz works for integrable model* [[arXiv:hep-th/9605187](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9605187)] focusses on spin chains mostly, which makes several constructions --- such as the introduction of an auxiliary space --- appear somewhat ad hoc; at least it certainly felt so to me when I first read them. The vertex-model point of view makes these constructions much more natural; this is also why I organized my lecture notes *A pedagogical introduction to quantum integrability, with a view towards theoretical high-energy physics*, [[arXiv:1501.06805](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.06805)] in the way I did.

Some more comments:

- Once you know the Lax matrix (containing the vertex weights) of the six- or eight-vertex model you can *solve* for the *R*-matrix (solving the "*RTT*-relation" with $T=L$ for the case of one site), see e.g. Sections 9.6 and 10.4 in Baxter, *Exactly solved models in statistical mechanics* (or Appendix C in my lecture notes mentioned above).
- Alternatively, you can look for solutions of the Yang--Baxter equation, and then interpret each *R*-matrix you get as a vertex model or see which spin chain it yields by computing the logarithmic derivative of the associated transfer matrix.
- It might be instructive to read up on another example: Shastry's *R*-matrix for the Hubbard model. See e.g. Section 12.2 in Essler, Frahm, Göhmann, Klümper, 
  Korepin, *The one-dimensional Hubbard model* [[e-print](http://max2.physics.sunysb.edu/~korepin/Hubbard.pdf)].

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! i understand what you're telling me, and i've seen your notes which seems very interesting, But : suppose that you don't know that XYZ model is integrable, so it's contradictory to find its R-matrix by using the "RTT" relation because the "RTT" is valid only if your model is integrable. In another hand if you look for solutions of Yang-Baxter equation directly, you can not  know for which model you're solving. What i was thinking  was : In order to find R-matrix for XYZ you have to find $Z_2 $ solutions of YBE, but i don't know if it's possible to do?

Comment: @Giuseppe You're welcome. I don't know of examples of models that were found to have an *R*-matrix without already expecting (or constructing) them to be quantum integrable. Here hints for the integrability (loosely: the existence of many conserved quantities) may for example come from  factorized scattering in a Bethe-ansatz type of solution.

Comment: @JulesLamers Yang-Baxter eq (YBE) seems to be a sufficient condition, i.e. if you have an R-matrix satisfying YBE, then the model is integrable. But how about the reverse? Do all 1+1d integrable spin-chain models have an R-matrix satisfying YBE? For example, spin-chain models having _discrete_ (say $\mathbb{Z}_2$) on-site symmetry, do these models have an R-matrix satisfying YBE?

Comment: @QGravity: That is a good question, but really beyond the OP. If you ask it as a separate question I'd be happy to write an answer. This will make it easier to find, which I think will be more useful for others

Comment: @JulesLamers thank you. I just did.

Comment: For easy reference: that question is https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/780311/